# Concat Loop Results to determine if contains value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, loop

I have the following code to retrieve the series of a product that has been purchased. We are using a loop because a contact might purchase multiple products.

```
 %%[IF NOT EMPTY(@PersonAccountId) 
   THEN set @MyWatchesTable = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("My_Watches__c","Product__c","Person_Account__c", "=", @PersonAccountId,"Status__c","=", "Owner") 
   SET @rowCount = RowCount(@MyWatchesTable) 
   IF @rowCount > 0 THEN 
   FOR @counter = 1 to @rowCount DO 
   SET @MyWatchesRow = Row(@MyWatchesTable, @counter) 
   SET @Product = Field(@MyWatchesRow,"Product__c") 
SET @ProductTable = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Product2","Series__c","Id", "=", @Product)
set @productCount = RowCount(@ProductTable)
set @ProductRow = Row(@ProductTable, @productCount) 
set @Series = Field(@ProductRow, "Series__c") 

]%%
-->
 Product %%=v(@counter)=%% : %%=v(@Product)=%%<br>
 Series %%=v(@productCount)=%% : %%=v(@Series)=%% <br>
 %%[ next @counter ]%% %%[ else ]%% No records found %%[ endif ]%%
<!-- %%[ENDIF]%%-->
```

I need to use the results of the loop to select the corresponding product checkbox if they own the product.

I wanted to concatenate the loop results

```
set @OutPutSeries = Concat(@counter, " ", @Product, " ", @productCount, " ", @Series, " ", next @counter)
```

and then use the the `IndexOf` to determine if the concatenated result contains one of the products

```
/* Does it match; ; if no match, output of IndexOf(1,2) will be "0" */ 
if IndexOf(@Series,'Connected') > 0 then 
    Set @OutputSoldConnected = "True"
else 
     Set @OutputSoldConnected = "False"
endif
```

Then use the True/False result to pre-populate the checkbox

I have tried to use the `indexOf` on the `@Series` variable but it only returns the last result, that is why I thought about concatenating them but it did not work.

As @Mark G I had to set the variable before the loop
`@ProductSeriesOutput` and declare the variable in the concatenation. Then I used the `IndexOf` function to check if the value I needed for the preference was available and selected the checkbox if matched.

```
 %%[IF NOT EMPTY(@PersonAccountId) 
   THEN 
   set @ProductSeriesOutput = " "
   set @MyWatchesTable = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("My_Watches__c","Product__c","Person_Account__c", "=", @PersonAccountId,"Status__c","=", "Owner") 
   SET @rowCount = RowCount(@MyWatchesTable) 
   IF @rowCount > 0 THEN 
   FOR @counter = 1 to @rowCount DO 
   SET @MyWatchesRow = Row(@MyWatchesTable, @counter) 
   SET @Product = Field(@MyWatchesRow,"Product__c") 
SET @ProductTable = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Product2","Series__c","Id", "=", @Product)
set @productCount = RowCount(@ProductTable)
set @ProductRow = Row(@ProductTable, @productCount) 
set @Series = Field(@ProductRow, "Series__c") 
set @ProductSeriesOutput = Concat(@ProductSeriesOutput, @counter, @Series," ")
next @counter
else 
endif


IF NOT EMPTY(@Series)
THEN

SET @HasTagHeuer = "True"

Var @OutputSoldConnected

/* Does it match; ; if no match, output of IndexOf(1,2) will be "0" */ 
if IndexOf(@ProductSeriesOutput,'Connected') > 0 then 
    Set @OutputSoldConnected = "True"
else 
     Set @OutputSoldConnected = "False"
endif 


ENDIF
]%%
-->

<!-- %%[ENDIF]%%-->
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to *append* values to a variable from within a loop, you'll need to remember to include the variable itself during concatenation. Otherwise, you'll simply be "re-setting" the variable after each iteration (i.e., the variable will be set according to the last iteration, only).

For example, this yields only the last result:

```
%%[
for @counter = 1 to 3 do
  set @series = Concat(@counter, " ")
next @counter
]%%
%%=V(@series)=%%
```

Output:

> 3

This, on the other hand, will yield all concatenated values:

```
%%[
set @series = "" /* initialize outside of loop */

for @counter = 1 to 3 do
  set @series = Concat(@series, @counter, " ") /* include existing value first */
next @counter
]%%
%%=V(@series)=%%
```

Output:

> 1 2 3

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and although I set the variable I want to display before the loop it does not work. 
Do you mean I need to set the Series before the loop and then define it in the loop twice? Please note I have updated the question with the recent code

Comment: @SYUYDY You need to concatenate the _same_ variable name to itself: `set @ProductSeriesOutput = Concat(@ProductSeriesOutput,@counter," ",@Series," ")`. Afterwards, `IndexOf()` will be used on `@ProductSeriesOutput` (_not_ `@Series`). Also, I count 2 `if` statements, but only 1 closing `endif` statement in your recent code, which means you're missing a final closing `endif` statement.

Comment: Thank you @Mark G that is clear now :)
It worked